# How does recursive type checking work in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Suppose we have the following typing scenario in Kotlin:

```
abstract class Baz<T : Baz<T>> : Foo<T> {
    override fun bar(t: T): T = this
}

interface Foo<Y> {
    fun bar(t: Y): Y
}
```

However, the compiler rejects the second line with the following error:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is Baz<T> but T was expected
```

The IDE plugin suggests changing the return type from `Baz.bar` to `Baz<T>`, producing:

```
abstract class Baz<T : Baz<T>> : Foo<T> {
    override fun bar(t: T): Baz<T> = this
}
```

However this also fails to compile with the following error:

```
Return type of 'bar' is not a subtype of the return type of the overridden member 'public abstract fun bar(t: Y): Y defined in Foo'
```

To satisfy the compiler, we must either cast `this as T` or modify the type definition:

```
abstract class Baz<T : Baz<T>> : Foo<Baz<T>> {
    override fun bar(t: Baz<T>): Baz<T> = this
}
```

But why is this necessary? Shouldn't `Baz<T>` be replaceable by `T`?

Comment: how are you going to create instance of Baz with such generic parameter(`class Baz<T : Baz<T>>`)?

Comment: `Baz` is not meant to be instantiated, at least not directly. But you might have another `class Bat: Baz<Bat>()` which could be, this is just omitted for simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following (simpler) case.

```
abstract class Baz<T: Baz<T>>  {
    fun bar(): T = this
}

class Bat: Baz<Bat>() {}

class Cat: Baz<Bat>() {}
```

According to the type signature of `Baz.bar()`, `Cat.bar()` should return an instance of `Bat` (because *T* is `Bat` in the definition of `Cat` class).  However, according to the definition of `Baz.bar()`, an instance of `Cat` will be returned because `this` is an instance of `Cat`.  This is an error as `Cat` is not a subclass of `Bat`.

Since any subclass `X` of `Baz` can be used as *T* when defining a subclass `Y` of `Baz`, there is no way to guarantee `this` in `bar` will be of type `X`; hence, the compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go over this one by one.

```
class Baz<T : Baz<T>> : Foo<T> {
    override fun bar(t: T): T = this
}

interface Foo<T> {
    fun bar(t: T): T
}
```

Here, you get the type mismatch error by compiler on the overriden `bar` function, which is obvious, as the return type is `T`, but you're returning `Baz<T>`. The compiler suggests you to change the return type as `Baz<T>` for you to assign `this` to the function and you get the below.

```
class Baz<T : Baz<T>> : Foo<T> {
    override fun bar(t: T): Baz<T> = this
}

interface Foo<T> {
    fun bar(t: T): T
}
```

Here, you again get a compiler error since `Baz<T>` is not a subtype of `T`. It is not possible for the compiler to ever know if `Baz<T>` can be a subtype of `T` unless you explicitly cast it, which can potentially lead to a cast exception. For eg, `List<String>` is not a subtype of `String`, or `Baz<Integer>` is not a subtype of `Integer`, unless you have implemented the inheritance. And hence the compiler can never know for sure if `Baz<T>` can be a subtype of `T` for it to be replaceable.

Since the interface is defined as below

```
interface Foo<T> {
    fun bar(t: T): T
}
```

Only the below are possible

```
class Baz<T : Baz<T>> : Foo<Baz<T>> {
    override fun bar(t: Baz<T>): Baz<T> = this
}
```

Or

```
class Baz<T : Baz<T>> : Foo<T> {
    override fun bar(t: T): T = this as T
}
```

But the second option has a possibility of cast exception if `Baz<T>` cannot be cast as `T`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. `Baz<T>` must be a subtype of `T`, as defined in the type bound, `T : Baz<T>`. I think you may be confusing the `T` in `interface Foo<T> {fun bar(t: T): T}` with the `T` in the type definition of `Baz`, which are unrelated. I have updated the question to clarify.